# Migrating MYSQL functions and stored procedures to SQL Server

Tags: database, mysql, sql-server, rdbms

The company i'm working for is selling HRIS management software. It was built using ASP and mysql.  But one of our client's demand is for it to be based on MS SQL Server. our team is made up mostly of junior programmers / fresh grad and we don't have much experience working in sql server and migrating from one db to another.

Can Mysql stored procedures be migrated to sql server using 'SQL Server Migration Assistant'?

If so, how?

If no, what other options do we have?

Comment: i'm sorry if did not provide additional details.

Comment: well.. just to make it short... we are selling a payroll processing / HRIS management app. But it was built with Mysql as DB. but the client wants to use Microsoft SQL Server.

Comment: The Help i need is:

Comment: how am i going to migrate mysql stored procedures / functions to sql server?

Comment: @LarrySolis most likely a rewrite.  What does the data access layer look like?  MySQL SP's for the DB interface? or are there queries in the code as well?  The differences between MySQL and MS Sql Server are enough that a migration is a rather large project.  From different data types to different builtin functions.

Comment: @WindRaven, yes there are queries in the code as well. :(

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is an implementation question involving a specific software tool.

Answer (score 0):

I'm fairly new to the SQL world as well. Don't let these guys get to you, they are ruthless sometimes (I'm getting a down vote for that!). Gnat is right though when it comes to your issue being a very Large Project. You had better believe that that is by design. Each company wants things done there own way and don't really like the idea of cross-platform. However, you will notice that almost all of them have developed a way to get databases from other platforms to migrate to their own (imagine that). Microsoft is no exception.

Microsoft SQL Server Migration Assistant v5.3 for MySQL

As you suggested, do a quick google search for the software above. It is free. It probably still wont be easy. Especially the stored procedures and the like. Microsoft does have some documentation on how to use it. Hope this helps.